# Gdb pending breakpoint does not resolve

Tags: c, debugging, assembly, gcc, gdb

My system is Debian 64 bit

I have written a simple hello world program in c

```
2       #include <string.h>
3
4       int main() {
5               char str_a[20];
6
7               strcpy(str_a, "Hello, world!\n");
8               printf(str_a);
9       }
```

Compiled it with
`gcc -g -o  char_array2 char_array2.c`
And fed into gdb via `gdb -q ./char_array2`

Now when i try to set up a breakpoint at strcpy like this

```
(gdb) break strcpy
Function "strcpy" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y
Breakpoint 2 (strcpy) pending.
(gdb)
```

and try to run it, the breakpoint is not resolved, "Hello world" is printed out and the program terminates.

What **SHOULD** have happenend after pressing run

`Breakpoint 4, 0xb7f076f4 in strcpy () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6`

Now i have read this in a book that teaches assembly on a 32bit system and also the path shows /i686/, so i suspect that there is some sort of funcitonality missing due to me using a 64bit processor. How can i fix this?

Comment: There probably is no actual call to `strcpy`. Instead, the compiler just inlined the necessary assembly to initialize the array.

Comment: Even with optimization disabled, GCC still treats `strcpy` as a builtin function and copies that copy from a literal into just a `mov`-immediate, because the arg is a constant part of the same statement.  https://godbolt.org/z/GvP8vn.  Compile with `-fno-builtin` if you want GCC to be dumb.

Comment: [What exactly is -fno-builtin doing here?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54281780) is an exact duplicate of your question, with the same source and the same problem, including the same GDB error message, except they're still compiling for 32-bit mode.  Maybe you got unlucky and the search terms you used didn't turn that up.

Answer (score 1):

When I compile your code with your compile options on x686, I get this:

```
    leaq    -32(%rbp), %rax
    movabsq $8583909746840200520, %rdx
    movq    %rdx, (%rax)
    movl    $1684828783, 8(%rax)
    movw    $2593, 12(%rax)
    movb    $0, 14(%rax)
```

Notice, there is no call to `strcpy`. The compiler has inlined the logic. With `-fno-builtin`, I get this:

```
    leaq    -32(%rbp), %rax
    leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rsi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    strcpy@PLT
    .loc 1 8 16
```